# Any existing C# code (OSS) that will calculate diff between two strings and output html?

Tags: c#, html, diff

I need to compare two strings and output the diff in HTML (similar to MS Word "track changes").  Language is C#, this is  (not surprisingly) a .NET web app.  There are a few similar questions (like [**this one for PHP/Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209800/difference-between-two-strings-in-python-php)), but no existing question on SO.

I don't need a finished project, just anything that will cut out the extra work.  I know this problem has been solved at least once.  I'm looking to leverage from that starting place (source for an object, just a method, just an algorithm in C#, anything will be useful).  Output for the diff needs to be in HTML.

Comment: Closing this question as off-topic a full 4 years after it has been asked and answered seems somewhat pointless and an indicator that these folks have waay too much time on their hands;  It's even more useless when you consider that it was closed after it has been fully and firmly entrenched in Google's index and (I'd wager) has helped tons of people; this is even more puzzling since very similar questions have been untouched;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a C# class available from [here](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/) (under a BSD licence) that will diff two textual inputs. If you download the source code, there is also some code that will turn this output into HTML. An example of its output can be found [here](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/DiffTest.aspx?oldfile=Diff.cs.v1&newfile=Diff.cs.v2).

Answer (score 1):

[DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/) and [Google Diff Match and Patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) (via prettyHtml function) are some other open source options.